# Next Js form sign up sending issues

Tags: post, next.js

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    try {
        const body = await request.json();

        const existingUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: {
                OR: [
                    { email: body.email },
                    { username: body.username }
                ]
            }
        });

        if (existingUser) {
            return new NextResponse('User already exists', { status: 409 }); // 409: Conflict
        }
        // Use Prisma to create a new record in the database
        const createdRecord = await prisma.user.create({
            data: {
                username: body.username,
                email: body.email,
                password: body.password,
                description: body.description,
                selectedTags: body.selectedTags,
            }
        });

        // Return the created record
        return NextResponse.json(createdRecord, { status: 201 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error processing request:', error);
        return new NextResponse('Invalid request', { status: 400 });
    }
}
```

I face an issue that this code doesn't send my form props to the database

I've tried to send request through postman and got and error "Invalid request" status 400

Comment: Is there a "Error processing request" message in the console along with that 400 error?